# Quasi-poisson for underdispersed data

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-regression, underdispersion

Related to `glm()` in R, I saw a few post recommending modeling underdispersed data using the Conway–Maxwell–Poisson distribution, specifically with the R package `CompGLM`, however, I'm not sure I saw anybody confirming that the quasi-poisson cannot be used. Therefore, I ask: why not use quasi-poisson in `glm` for underdispersed data? After all, isn't the idea of quasi-poisson to go beyond the assumption that variance and mean are equal ? (and in the case of underdispersion, there are not equal).

Basically, I am running a `glm(y ~ x, family=poisson)` where x is a categorical variable and I am getting

```
Null deviance: 67.905  on 519  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 59.584  on 507  degrees of freedom
```

Which strongly suggest underdispersion and I am therefore leaning towards a quasi-poisson solution.

Comment: The quasi-Poisson can definitely be used. I don't know enough about COM-Poisson to say whether, or under what conditions, it would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quasi-likelihood theory is as valid with underdispersed data as it is with overdispersed data, so you could just go that way.

But, I would be careful, context matters a lot. While overdispersion is quite common, and is easily explained by simple mechanisms, that is **not** the case with underdispersion! For instance, extra, unmodeled (or unobserved) variation/inhomogeneities leads to overdispersion, but can **never** produce underdispersion. Causes for underdispersion are more difficult to come by, they usually have to do with a lack of independence. For one example see [Causes for Underdispersion in Poisson Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317598/causes-for-underdispersion-in-poisson-regression).  One common cause of lack of independence is *competion*, an example I just come by is counts of territorial birds (that was from my daughters masters thesis in ecology)!

Some posts dealing with practical matters when modeling with underdispersion is

- [GLM for proportional data and underdispersion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134783/glm-for-proportional-data-and-underdispersion),
- [Overdispersion and Underdispersion in Negative Binomial/Poisson Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133635/overdispersion-and-underdispersion-in-negative-binomial-poisson-regression),
- [Is there a common underdispersed discrete distribution with unbounded support for general mean and variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372376/is-there-a-common-underdispersed-discrete-distribution-with-unbounded-support-fo),
- [Are these data underdispersed? If so, what mechanisms may explain this?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123123/are-these-data-underdispersed-if-so-what-mechanisms-may-explain-this)